# Type conversion from byte slice to struct with unsafe

Tags: go, types, unsafe-pointers

I'm trying to understand why my code in Go doesn't work the way I thought it would. When I execute this test, it fails:

```
func TestConversion(t *testing.T) {
    type myType struct {
        a     uint8
        value uint64
    }
    myVar1 := myType{a: 1, value: 12345}

    var copyFrom []byte
    copyFromHeader := (*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&copyFrom))
    copyFromHeader.Data = uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&myVar1))
    copyFromHeader.Cap = 9
    copyFromHeader.Len = 9

    copyTo := make([]byte, len(copyFrom))

    for i := range copyFrom {
        copyTo[i] = copyFrom[i]
    }

    myVar2 := (*myType)(unsafe.Pointer(&copyFrom[0]))
    myVar3 := (*myType)(unsafe.Pointer(&copyTo[0]))

    if myVar2.value != myVar3.value {
        t.Fatalf("Expected myVar3.value to be %d, but it is %d", myVar2.value, myVar3.value)
    }
}
```

The output will be:

```
slab_test.go:67: Expected myVar3.value to be 12345, but it is 57
```

However, if I increase `copyFromHeader.Data` by `1` before the copying of the data, then it all works fine. Like this:

```
copyFromHeader.Data = uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&myVar1)) + 1
```

I don't understand why it seems to shift the underlying data by one byte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 7 padding bytes between `a` and `value`. You're only getting the least significant byte of 12345 (57) in `value`. When you move `copyFrom` down by one byte, the values of `myVar2.value` and `myVar3.value` are both 48 (the second byte of 12345), so your test passes. It should work if you change 9 to 16.

Is there some particular reason you're copying the struct that way?

Comment: Thank you so much, you're right!
We're trying to put a simple struct with a `uint` and a `uint8` into a byte slice that we got returned from `syscall.Mmap`. But when we tried to cast that byte slice back into the struct it's supposed to be we ran into this issue.